# How to remove few tables from a large SQL file?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql5

I have a SQL file with size around 3 GB. So this takes some long time to restore every time when i took recent dump from production.

In this one table 'access_log' itself took 2.2 GB which is just a log. For testing purpose its OK to have that table empty. Is there any way to avoid this table while restoring the database.

My command for restoring looks like

```
mysqldump -u uname -p pwd --no-data site_name_com | awk '/DROP TABLE/ { print }' | mysql -u uname -p pwd site_name_com && mysql -u uname -p pwd site_name_com < /..file_path../..file_name.sql
```

**How can I make a database dump that excludes one specific table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqldump` output format is simply a long list of SQL commands, meant to be fed back into the `mysql` program.

You can use `mysqldump --ignore-table=<database>.<table>` to create a dump that does not include the `access_log` table at all.

Then you can use `mysqldump --no-data=true` to dump just the structure for the `access_log` table.

If you concatenate the two, you will have a complete dump script that excludes the data for the `access_log` table.

As long as you only need to do this for one or a few tables, and control the original mysqldump invocation, that should be a practical solution.

Googled for *mysqldump exclude table*, which brought up my main source of inspiration which was the [Skip certain tables with mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425158/486504) Stack Overflow question, and [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/425172/486504).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL file generated by `mysqldump`, it should contain comments indicating what the next lines do.

Example:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `access_log`
--
```

We can use them to filter out ranges of statements while streaming the file to the mysql command.

For instance, to ignore anything between two `CREATE TABLE` statements, we can do:

```
cat backup.sql | sed '/Dumping data for table `first_table_to_skip`/,/Dumping data for table `next_table_to_include`/d' | mysql
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996602/307692) for more information about this feature of sed.